# MoMS Crane Wing + Linnorm Vengeance

Tags: pathfinder-1e, fighting-style

> [Crane Wing (Combat)](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/crane-wing-combat/)
>
> When fighting defensively with at least one hand free, you gain a +4
>   dodge bonus to AC against melee attacks. If a melee attack misses you
>   by 4 or less, you lose this dodge bonus until the beginning of your
>   next turn.

---

> [Linnorm Vengeance (Combat)](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/linnorm-vengeance-combat/)
>
> If a creature’s melee attack would normally miss you, you can allow it
>   to hit you to gain this bonus; the attack deals the minimum amount of
>   damage (as though the attacker had rolled a natural 1 on each damage
>   die).

While playing a Master of Many Styles, if I allow an attack to hit me for minimum damage when it would otherwise miss, would it still remove Crane Wing's dodge bonus?

Comment: Are you actually considering this combination for a PC or NPC or is this purely curiosity? (I ask because if it's purely curiosity then answers needn't go into *great* detail about this combination's (lack of) efficacy, although any good answer should still address its potency a little.)

Comment: IDK I feel like (specifically on a Master of Many Styles because they have bonus feats *to use for* styles) it's actually a pretty solid combo. Net neutral to hit (or +1 if you take Crane Riposte) for 6 AC and Wisdom to damage. I've seen a tank monk be untouchable with Crane and some other defensive investment. I think giving up Flurry is the biggest drawback, but that's an issue with the archetype not the feats. Granted, it's not pummeling dragon style, but if they're wanting to balance offense and defense this seems to work.

Comment: Getting to pick if you take minimum damage (especially on things like sneak attack) to keep your AC up against iterative attacks is a significant benefit, albeit for a small gap of your AC. Anything over or under that gap has its own benefits, either because you were missed thanks to Crane Style or because Linnorm lets you retaliate.

Comment: @Ifusaso At low levels I agree that this combination may have some significance. However, minimum damage at mid or high levels is often only 1–12 points different from a foe's *maximum* damage. For example, a CR 15 frost giant blackguard that's using the feat Power Attack will thank the stylist for letting him deal his "minimum" damage!

Comment: While I agree generally, in such a case you have the option of giving up the 4 AC to still have the attack miss. The strength of the combo is the flexibility. Is it going to set the standard for making a Monk? No. But I do think it can keep up with other Monk builds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### You retain the dodge bonus.

Although these two abilities were probably not "designed" to interact, the actual text seems pretty conclusive. Specifically Crane Style

> [...] **misses** you by 4 or less [...]

and Linnorm Vengeance

> [...] melee attack **would normally miss you**, you can *allow it to hit you* [...]

The only word that would lock it in better would be included "instead". However, it's pretty strongly implied that the hit is a hit *instead* of a miss. The language "would normally" makes it implicit that the attack no longer misses.

Comment: While I think you could make a good case in either direction, this is how I would rule it were I the DM. If you allow an attack to hit you with Linnorm Vengeance, then the "misses you by 4 or less" clause is irrelevant.

Comment: I could definitely "see" ruling the other way, but this is the literal meaning of the words used. The fact that they use a negative in reference to the same term "miss" does that. Of course leaving out the word "instead" leaves some grey area